# Display common elements and differences of 2 DataFrames with different size

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames containing strings values. They have different sizes as well. I would like to display the common elements and the differences between the 2 DataFrames.

My approach is: I created a function compare(DataFrame1, DataFrame2) which will compare using equals method the 2 DataFrames. If they are the same then I don't need to find any more the differences. I need a second function which will actually show the differences between the DataFrames. Can someone help me continue?

```
def test2_expansion():
    test1 = graph.run('match (n:Disease)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(m:Disease) where n.id ="C0039446" return distinct m.id order by m.id;')
    test1 = pd.DataFrame(test1.data())
    return test1

g = test2_expansion()
g = g.to_dict(orient='list')
print ("The result of test 2 for expansion in Neo4j is ")
for key, value in g.items():
    for n in value:
        print(n)


def compareResults(a,b):
    if a.equals(b):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def takeDifferences():
     a = "Search differences"
     if (compareResult() == True):
        return "Amaizing!"
     else:
        return a


DataFrame1       
C0494228             
C0272078
C2242772

DataFrame2
C2242772
C1882062
C1579212
C1541065
C1306459
C0442867
C0349036
C0343748
C0027651
C0272078

Display Common Elements: C0272078 C2242772
Elements found only in DataFrame1:C0494228
Elements found only in DataFrame2:C2242772
C1882062
C1579212
C1541065
C1306459
C0442867
C0349036
C0343748
C0027651
```

Comment: this is how I get the result of the DataFrame: g = dataFrame1()
g = g.to_dict(orient='list')
print ("The result of test 2 for expansion in Neo4j is ")
for key, value in g.items():
    for n in value:
        print(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you now my generic function which will answer my question

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a.equals(b):
        print("SAME!")
    else:
        df = a.merge(b, how='outer',indicator=True)
        x = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'both', 'm.id']
        y = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'left_only', 'm.id']
        z = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'right_only', 'm.id']
        print (f'Display Common Element: {", ".join(x)}')
        print (f'Elements found only in DataFrame1: {", ".join(y)}')
        print (f'Elements found only in DataFrame2: {", ".join(z)}')
```

In this moment my function returns None because I don't know if I should return something, but it works perfectly. Thank you @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

If there are DataFrames with columns same - e.g. `m.id` use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
print (df)
        m.id      _merge
0   C0494228   left_only
1   C0272078        both
2   C2242772        both
3   C1882062  right_only
4   C1579212  right_only
5   C1541065  right_only
6   C1306459  right_only
7   C0442867  right_only
8   C0349036  right_only
9   C0343748  right_only
10  C0027651  right_only
```

And then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'both', 'm.id']
b = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'left_only', 'm.id']
c = df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'right_only', 'm.id']
```

Last join values with `f-string`s:

```
print (f'Display Common Element: {", ".join(a)}')
Display Common Element: C0272078, C2242772

print (f'Elements found only in DataFrame1: {", ".join(b)}')
Elements found only in DataFrame1: C0494228

print (f'Elements found only in DataFrame2: {", ".join(c)}')
Elements found only in DataFrame2: C1882062, C1579212, C1541065, 
                                   C1306459, C0442867, C0349036, 
                                   C0343748, C0027651
```

Comment: everything works until filtering. then I get an error: KeyError: 'the label [col] is not in the [columns]'

Comment: @StetcoOana - What is  `print (df1.info())` and `print (df2.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 49 entries, 0 to 48
Data columns (total 1 columns):
m.id    49 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 472.0+ bytes
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 39 entries, 0 to 38
Data columns (total 1 columns):
m.id    39 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 392.0+ bytes
None
[Finished in 3.445s]

Comment: yes. my DataFrames have only one column having that string.

Comment: and multiple rows with one column containing that string

Comment: m.id is the name of the column

Comment: in both data frames, I have m.id which is the column name.  both dataFrames have indexes.

Comment: @StetcoOana - Yes, in answer was changed `col` to `m.id`, so now it should working nice.